# Why does Sister Charlotte have a baby blanket in her suitcase?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-conjuring-universe, annabelle-creation

In *Annabelle: Creation*, when Sister Charlotte was unpacking her suitcase in the beginning why was there a baby blanket?

Answer (score 5):

Charlotte had a baby blanket in her suitcase because she had a baby who she gave up for adoption. She cherished this baby blanket as a keepsake. They eliminated it from the film.

[reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/horror/comments/6sxpg2/official_dreadit_discussion_annabelle_creation/):

> Yeah about the pacing, we shot too much script. The first cut of the
>   film was over 2 hours. I cut out as much as possible, like this whole
>   backstory about **Charlotte having a kid who she gave up for adoption
>   that later died and comes back to haunt her (there's still a shot in
>   the film of Charlotte looking at a baby blanket)**. Also once Janice got
>   possessed she hung around the house for a few days which felt wrong.
>   Once she's possessed you want to get moving.
>
> I prefer movies that are closer to 90 min but didn't feel like I could
>   take that much more out of this film without hurting things in some
>   ways.

[Annabelle Creation Extended scene (Sister Charlottes son)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8YIFZu1Dh1U)